# Automatically convert character pattern in CKEditor

Tags: javascript, regex, ckeditor

Whenever a user enters physical dimensions like `122.3x90.5` into CKEditor, this should be converted to `122.3×90.5` (notice the correct multiplication symbol).

I know the correct regex: `$replacement = '/(?<=\d\ )x(?= \d)/'`.

But how can I implement it in CKEditor so the symbol is correct in the resulting HTML code?

Comment: Regex doesn't seem to be correct either. Like those spaces and single quotes and more importantly JS doesn't support lookbehinds.

Answer (score 0):

It could be replaced as user type, using e.g. `change` event listener ([PoC](https://jsfiddle.net/e192hrdf/)). The other solution, more user-friendly, is to do such replacement inside our data processor, used by `editor.getData` method ([PoC](https://jsfiddle.net/svrsncuf/)).